# Setting up CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm working on a big codebase that frequently makes use of [CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce.html) and [Root](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Root.html).  For example,

`criteriaBuilder.coalesce(root.get('adjustedWeight'), root.get('weight'))`

I don't understand this syntax.  For one, the [Coalesce API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce.html) appears to accept only 1 argument of type `Expression<? extends T>` or `T`.  I also do not understand what Root is or why it is useful.

In order to help me understand, I'm creating a simplified example that uses the line of code above, with CriteriaBuilder and Root.  I have successfully wired up Hibernate and JPA.

*Please keep in mind I have ~3 days of Java programming experience.  My native langugage is C#*

```
import models.MyEntity;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {
    public static final String SELECT_QUERY = "from MyEntity where title = :title";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String title = "secureexam";
            PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = persistenceProvider
                    .createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit", new HashMap());
            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            List<MyEntity> result = entityManager
                    .createQuery(SELECT_QUERY, MyEntity.class)
                    .setParameter("title", title)
                    .getResultList();

            System.out.println("result is " + result.get(0).getTitle());
            entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Can you please explain the first line of code to me regarding criteriaBuilder?  Also, how can I modify my code to make use of this line of code?

**UPDATE**

The article mentioned in Kevin Peters answer worked with slight modification:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Entity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Entity.class);

//Test 1
Root<AssessmentEntity> rootTest1 = criteriaQuery.from(Entity.class);
```

In other words, `CriteriaBuilder` and `CriteriaQuery` had to be instantiated differently for the build to work.  E.G. the whole `CriteriaQuery<Entity class>` syntax didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you got the wrong API documentation, the proper one is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#coalesce-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-). The coalesce method (like the [SQL pendant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#COALESCE)) just returns the first non-null value, so either the value of `adjustedWeight` if that is not null, otherwise the value of `weight`, or at least null if none of the values is present.

The `root` variable in your case just represents the table you are working on, respective which represents the root of your query (the SQL query translation would be `... FROM ...`). The name is arbitrary. [As database term this would be the selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_(relational_algebra)). [This article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_criteria_api.htm) could also help you.